# How to display 2 Columns and multiple Row in a UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift5

I want to display multiple columns in a UITableView.

For Example:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFIY1.png)

Comment: Why are you not using UICollectionView it is meant for this purpose. But if you insist on UITableview Why not create a cell which looks like two comuns?

Comment: If any one know this . Please help me.  Thanks to you in advance